# SQL JOINS (changing LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN)

Tags: sql

How to modify a Query using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT countries.name AS country,languages.name AS language,percent
FROM countries 
RIGHT JOIN languages AS languages
USING (code)
ORDER BY languages
```

Comment: Reverse the join type along with the two tables.

Comment: Why would you need to outer-right-join anyway, always found this unintuitive as does everyone I work with, finding queries that use both join types is abhorrent!

Comment: Do you want to include countries without any language, or languages without any country?

Comment: Change tables position, how recommended @shawnt00

Comment: `right`/`left` join returns all the rows of `right`/`left` table and corresponding rows of `left`/`right` table that satisfy the join predicate. As you may see, to change `right`/`left` to other type you need to swap tables and join type. But right join is really not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate it:

List of departments (4 of them):

```
SQL> select * from dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Employees who work in these departments; nobody works in department 40:

```
SQL> select * from temp order by deptno;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME
---------- ---------- ----------
        10       7782 CLARK
        20       7369 ADAMS
        30       7499 ALLEN
```

Left join:

```
SQL> select deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join temp e using (deptno)     --> this line will be modified
  3  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        40 OPERATIONS
```

Right join: substitute `left` with `right` and exchange tables' positions:

```
SQL> select deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from temp e right join dept d using (deptno)     --> note the difference here
  3  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        40 OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

Result is the same (as should be).